# Horizontal menu bar with arrows in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a mobile menu with arrows using this fiddle.

[Jsfillde](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc46wmu9/)

But there is a problem. When I add more list items and press right arrow, it will go to the end of list. So we can't see middle li elements.

I just want to see middle items by showing left, right arrow both in the middle and slowly moving left or right.

I tried with adding this code..

```
if (menuPosition <= paddleMargin) {
        $(leftPaddle).addClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    } else if (menuPosition < menuEndOffset) {
        // show both paddles in the middle
        $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    } else if (menuPosition >= menuEndOffset) {
        $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).addClass('hidden');
}
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: are you using click event any function ? please share your full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the scroll amount, so instead of scrolling the full width it instead only scrolls a set amount of pixels each click. To try this you just need to replace:

```
// scroll to left
$(rightPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: menuInvisibleSize}, scrollDuration);
});

// scroll to right
$(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: '0' }, scrollDuration);
});
```

With something like this:

```
var scrollAmount = 0;

// scroll to left
$(rightPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: scrollAmount += 100 }, scrollDuration);
});

// scroll to right
$(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: scrollAmount -= 100 }, scrollDuration);
});
```

Comment: I had the same idea but I couldn't figure out how to pass a dynamic value using the `animate()` function, you got a +1 from me and I learned something in exchange.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Actually there is no need of this new variable scrollAmount , check my answer, almost same with a little change, and yes if the width of items changed then it will not work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

### Check I've done this same as you want

```js
// duration of scroll animation
var scrollDuration = 300;
// paddles
var leftPaddle = document.getElementsByClassName('left-paddle');
var rightPaddle = document.getElementsByClassName('right-paddle');
// get items dimensions
var itemsLength = $('.item').length;
var itemSize = $('.item').outerWidth(true);
// get some relevant size for the paddle triggering point
var paddleMargin = 20;

// get wrapper width
var getMenuWrapperSize = function() {
  return $('.menu-wrapper').outerWidth();
}
var menuWrapperSize = getMenuWrapperSize();
// the wrapper is responsive
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  menuWrapperSize = getMenuWrapperSize();
});
// size of the visible part of the menu is equal as the wrapper size 
var menuVisibleSize = menuWrapperSize;

// get total width of all menu items
var getMenuSize = function() {
  return itemsLength * itemSize;
};
var menuSize = getMenuSize();
// get how much of menu is invisible
var menuInvisibleSize = menuSize - menuWrapperSize;

// get how much have we scrolled to the left
var getMenuPosition = function() {
  return $('.menu').scrollLeft();
};

// finally, what happens when we are actually scrolling the menu
$('.menu').on('scroll', function() {

  // get how much of menu is invisible
  menuInvisibleSize = menuSize - menuWrapperSize;
  // get how much have we scrolled so far
  var menuPosition = getMenuPosition();

  var menuEndOffset = menuInvisibleSize - paddleMargin;

  // show & hide the paddles 
  // depending on scroll position
  if (menuPosition <= paddleMargin) {
    $(leftPaddle).addClass('hidden');
    $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
  } else if (menuPosition < menuEndOffset) {
    // show both paddles in the middle
    $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
  } else if (menuPosition >= menuEndOffset) {
    $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    $(rightPaddle).addClass('hidden');
  }

  // print important values
  $('#print-wrapper-size span').text(menuWrapperSize);
  $('#print-menu-size span').text(menuSize);
  $('#print-menu-invisible-size span').text(menuInvisibleSize);
  $('#print-menu-position span').text(menuPosition);

});

// scroll to left
var scroll = $('.menu').scrollLeft();
$(rightPaddle).on('click', function() {
  scroll += ($('.menu').width() - $('.left-paddle').width() * 2);
  $('.menu').animate({
    scrollLeft: scroll
  }, scrollDuration);
});

// scroll to right
$(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
  scroll -= ($('.menu').width() - $('.left-paddle').width() * 2);
  $('.menu').animate({
    scrollLeft: scroll
  }, scrollDuration);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 3em;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.menu {
  height: 120px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.menu .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.paddle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3em;
}

.left-paddle {
  left: 0;
}

.right-paddle {
  right: 0;
}

.hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
}

.print {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.print span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <!--
-->
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <!--
-->
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <!--
-->
    <li class="item">4</li>
    <!--
-->
    <li class="item">5</li>
    <!--
-->
    <li class="item">6</li>
    <li class="item">7</li>
    <li class="item">8</li>
    <li class="item">9</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="paddles">
    <button class="left-paddle paddle hidden">
   <
  </button>
    <button class="right-paddle paddle">
   >
  </button>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="print" id="print-wrapper-size"><span></span> Wrapper / visible menu size</div>
<div class="print" id="print-menu-size"><span></span> Total menu size</div>
<div class="print" id="print-menu-invisible-size"><span></span> Invisible menu size</div>
<div class="print" id="print-menu-position"><span></span> Scroll position</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: By copying the idea of the other answer? Great job :)

Answer (score 1):

If the width of your itesm will increase or decrease then it will be more suitable.
replace this

```
$(rightPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: menuInvisibleSize}, scrollDuration);
});

// scroll to right
$(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: '0' }, scrollDuration);
});
```

with this only,

```
$(rightPaddle).on('click', function(e) {
        $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: '+=' + itemSize }, scrollDuration);
    });

    // scroll to right
    $(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
        $('.menu').animate({ scrollLeft: '-=' + itemSize }, scrollDuration);
    });
```